# Why are my polygon features area being calculated as zero?

Tags: arcmap, area

I am trying to measure the area of polygons within a larger polygon. However some of them, seemingly without reason are being calculated as having zero area. The highlighted regions are calculated as zero and the non highlighted features are being calculated correctly:

[image: The highlighted regions are calculated as zero and the non highlighted features are being calculated correctly]

Any ideas on why this is happening? I took the buildings, used buffer to create the borders, and then dissolved them.

Comment: Run the repair geometry tool on them first, then try again.

Comment: I second what @Hornbydd says, if it doesn't work try Check Validity and see if there are any invalid results that need to be fixed.

Comment: Repair geometry didnt work, and I dont have a Check Validity.

Comment: Where did you write this data too, i.e. what format?

Comment: Shapefile, is that what youre asking?

Comment: Since you are using a dataset of buildings, I assume you have a lot of features (maybe more than 500K?).  I have problems with shapefiles when using large datasets.  Try writing the data to a GDB instead.

Comment: Are you working with a geographic coordinate system or a projected coordinate system (for each feature class)? Also, are you trying to measure what appears to be building footprints within the polygons?

Comment: I fixed it by calculating the geometry in Arcgis Pro instead of Arcmap -_-

Comment: don't forget that ArcMap calculates the area (Geometry) only for the selected records (if any record is selected).
Plz verify that there is no selected record before starting the calculate geometry process